# Websockets and synchronous function calls

Tags: java, websocket, synchronous

I'm working on Java client-server application that need real time events. I've begin with a mix of RESTful web services (for synchronous request/response) and websockets (for events processing). Is there a way to use websockets in java for synchronous request/response? So I can use only websockets for my application.

Comment: This might be helpful: [The Java EE 7 Tutorial: Java API for WebSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm)

Comment: I've read it, but I see only usage for asynchronous messaging